# Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzd

Tags: android, firebase, dependencies

While rebuilding my project I got this error:

Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzd

Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzd, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
 }
 }
```

dependencies

```
dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

//add library
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project `build.gradle file` change:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

to:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
```